# Test e-mail with previous version of iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, mail.app, email

The email app on my ipad suddenly stopped working without me changing any settings. I don't know if upgrading to the latest version of iOS might be the reason but I want to exclude it.

Is there a way I could test my e-mail with previous version of iOS? I'm looking for an app or some software to install on my Macbook which would let me test things locally.

Is it possible with xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to test on a previous version of iOS on an iPad/iPhone/iPod is to actually restore a backup to the version or wipe out the existing version and install a previous version over it.

There's no app that will allow you to do what you're looking for because the devices just won't allow it.

It's rare that an iOS update *itself* will cause the stock mail app to stop working.  You didn't mention what mail app you were using so I can only assume it's Mail.

With Xcode, you can run various different iOS versions on the simulator only.  If that will work for you then that's your only chance at testing.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have backups going way back and yes, the app is Mail. I just need to enter username, password and server name. Would the simulator allow me to do that or is it just a bare bones environment without the default apps?

Comment: I'm not sure if the simulators have Mail installed.  I haven't had a reason to look for it and I don't recall from memory.  If you don't have an app's source code, I don't think it can be installed on a simulator.  Instead, you can install a free, 3rd-party mail app on your iPhone, configure it for your mailbox(es) and see if it works.